# Simple form using HTML and PHP - page not found

Tags: php, forms

I'm looking to send data from an HTML form to an email address using PHP. I have the following code in index.html:

```
<form class="container" name="rsvp" method="POST" action="form-to-email.php">
    <input type="text" class="name" name="name" placeholder="Your Name" />
    <input type="email" class="email" name="email" placeholder="Your Email" />
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Send"/>
```

In the same directory I have form-to-email.php:

```
    <?php 
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {

$to = "myemail@gmail.com";
$subject = "RSVP";
$name_field = $_POST['name'];
$email_field = $_POST['email'];

$body = "From: $name_field\n E-Mail: $email_field\n";

echo "<h1>Your form has been submitted</h1>";
mail($to, $subject, $body);
} else {
echo "<h1>Error</h1>";
}
?>
```

When I click the submit button, I get a 'Page not working' error.

I am extremely new to PHP so I can't understand what is going wrong. I'm using Live Server with VS code and the website is currently being hosted on port 5500.

Should I have another server running in order for PHP to work? I believe I have PHP installed on my machine (Mac), but I don't know if I need to start up XAMMP or something similar even for a simple form like this to work? And if this is the case, how would the form then function on a live server? I usually use Netlify to host my projects.

Comment: Check your error log for the exact error. Type php in terminal and see what happens.

Comment: `Page not working` isn't really an HTTP error code. To try to work out what the real error is, you can do things like this: turn on browser error reporting; remove all the code from the php page and just leave some text; try using a non-existent url to POST to and see whether you  get a different error. Basically try to narrow down the possible causes by removing options one by one. This feels like it might be a 500 error caused by a bug in the php.

Comment: @ChrisLear - I've changed the code to a single echo statement and it still doesn't work. I've also tried using a random URL to post to and get the same error. The error is a 405.

Comment: @Grumpy - how do I got about checking the error log?

Comment: 405 means "Method Not Allowed" as I'm sure you've discovered. Your web server is set up so that POST is not allowed. That means that changing the php is irrelevant and so is changing the html. This is a question about configuring the web server.